# Mongoose text search is not returning the correct result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a recipe blog website using mongoose, nodejs and express. I am making a search form, but the text search not giving the correct output.

In **Recipe.js** schema I added the following parameters, that in which values I want to search, I'm added the following ones: `recipeSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text', ingredients: 'text', categoryByNationality: 'text', categoryByServing: 'text'});`

When I started this project, i had only `recipeSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text',});` and it's worked, but after a few months later I added the *ingredients, categoryByNationality and categoryByServing* and when I search for category, not finding any recipe. If I search for name and description, its working fine. When I delete all this `recipeSchema.index({.......})` code, working with the name and with description again.

What is causing this problem, any idea?

**Controller.js**

```
exports.searchRecipe = async(req, res) => {

    //searchTerm
    try {
        let searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
        let recipe = await Recipe.find({ $text: { $search: searchTerm, $diacriticSensitive: true } });
        res.render('search', { title: 'Cooking Blog - Search', recipe });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({message: error.message || "Error Occured"});
    }
}
```

**Recipe schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    servings: {
        type: Number,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Array,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    ingredients: {
        type: Array,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    categoryByServing: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Reggeli', 'Ebéd', 'Vacsora', 'Desszert', 'Levesek', 'Egyéb'],
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    categoryByNationality: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Thai', 'Kínai', 'Indiai', 'Olasz', 'Angol', 'Magyar', 'Egyéb'],
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    image: {
        type: Array,
        required: 'This field is required.'
    },
    comments: [
        {
            username: String,           
            comment: String,          
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },           
            rating: Number,
        },{
            timestamps: true
        }
    ],
    count: {
        type: Number
    },
    likes: {
        type: Number
    },
    ratingAvg: {
        type: Number
    },
    recipe_id: {
        type: String
    }

});

recipeSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text', ingredients: 'text', categoryByNationality: 'text', categoryByServing: 'text'});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
```

**search.ejs**

```
<h1 class="pb-4">Search result</h1>

<div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-5 g-2 g-lg-3">
    <% if(typeof recipe !== 'undefined' && recipe.length > 0) { %>
      <% recipe.forEach(function(recipe, index){ %>
      <a href="/recipe/<%= recipe._id %>" class="col text-center category_link">
        <div class="category_img category__img--large shadow">
          <img src="/uploads/<%= recipe.image %>" alt="<%= recipe.name %>" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div class="pt-1"><%= recipe.name %></div>
      </a>
      <% }) %>
    <% } else { %>
      <p>Cant find any recipe</p>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

**Sample data for Recipe database**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6228ce14b72c51796e00b8ce"
    },
    "name": "Test recipe",
    "description": "test test test",
    "servings": {
        "$numberInt": "6"
    },
    "quantity": ["12", "20", "2"],
    "ingredients": ["l water", "g salt", "l milk"],
    "categoryByServing": "Ebéd",
    "categoryByNationality": "Indiai",
    "image": ["1646744388278274327802_7801262463232661_4968108751943235625_n.jpg"],
    "comments": [{
        "username": "First username",
        "comment": "First comment",
        "rating": {
            "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "622753706aff227ef4b4460a"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1646744433049"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "username": "Second username",
        "comment": "Second comment",
        "rating": {
            "$numberInt": "4"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6227537e6aff227ef4b44615"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1646744446326"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "username": "Third username",
        "comment": "Third comment",
        "rating": {
            "$numberInt": "3"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "622753896aff227ef4b44622"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1646744458103"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "username": "Fourth username",
        "comment": "Fourth comment",
        "rating": {
            "$numberInt": "2"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6227539e6aff227ef4b44631"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1646744478781"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "username": "Fifth username",
        "comment": "Fifth comment",
        "rating": {
            "$numberInt": "1"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "622753a86aff227ef4b44642"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1646744489088"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "username": "25",
        "comment": "gasss",
        "rating": {
            "$numberInt": "3"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "622796829f8062416492dcfd"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1646761603076"
            }
        }
    }],
    "count": {
        "$numberInt": "120"
    },
    "likes": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    },
    "ratingAvg": {
        "$numberDouble": "3.0"
    },
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you [drop the previous index before creating the new one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#recreating-an-existing-index)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs That was the problem, I didn't used the dropindex. I'm added the following code: Recipe.collection.dropIndexes(); so now its working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To "change" an index in MongoDB, first the previous index must be dropped.

```
Recreating an Existing Index

If you call db.collection.createIndex() for an index
that already exists, MongoDB does not recreate the index.
```

[MongoDB Manual: db.collection.createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#recreating-an-existing-index).